# Form serialize does not include table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function to check if something was changed in the form, apparently it worked perfectly:

```js
$(function() {
  var init_form = $('#editarproduto').serialize();

  $(':submit').click(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  });

  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var check_form = $('#editarproduto').serialize();
    console.log(check_form);
    console.log(init_form);
    if (check_form === init_form) 
      return null;

    return 'Os dados do formulário não foram salvos, deseja permanecer nesta página?';
  };
});
```

But it came up with his need to check the table, if something was hidden in it, it does not take the changes in this table:

```html
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tabelaf" name="tabelaf">
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores) {
      <tr class="tr item">
        <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Id</td>
        <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
        <td align="right">
          <a class="link-excluir" href="#" data-id="@item.Id" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How do you compare it to this table too?

Comment: `serialize()` only reads form controls, of which a `table` is not one. If you want to check if the table has been amended you could set a flag at the point you change the table, or compare the original/current table HTML in the same manner as you are now with the serialised form data.

Comment: I see no form elements in your table

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you have any examples to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serialize is getting data only from form elements. You can add hidden inputs to your columns to include this data to the form:

```
<td>
  @item.FornecedorProduto.Id
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.FornecedorProduto.Id" />
</td>
```

Note that this table should be placed inside of your form